# check for multiple collisions at sprites in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am currently working with pygame, and I want to create multiple sprites and check for at least two collisions. I came up with the idea of having two while - loops but it ended up being really complicated. Is there any other way I could try it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Also see the specifics on posting a coding problem: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: What is your game ? Just handle the position of your objects, and compare them. If they are the same point, then a collision appear. You can also use the colors to check the collision like in Unity.

Comment: This is something you should learn by reading a tutorial like [Program Arcade Games' sprite chapter](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13), but I can give you an example if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to get a list of the sprites that collide with the player, then loop over this list to do something with the collided sprites.

There's also [`groupcollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) which you can use to detect collisions between two sprite groups. It returns a dictionary with sprites of group 1 as the keys and the collided sprites of group 2 as the values.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((120, 60))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((120, 60))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    enemy_group = pg.sprite.Group(Enemy((200, 250)), Enemy((350, 250)))
    all_sprites.add(enemy_group)
    player = Player((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                player.rect.center = event.pos

        all_sprites.update()
        # Check which enemies collided with the player.
        # spritecollide returns a list of the collided sprites.
        collided_enemies = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_group, False)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        for enemy in collided_enemies:
            # Draw rects around the collided enemies.
            pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 190, 120), enemy.rect, 4)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! That helped a lot!! I'm new on pygame and have trouble sometimes to code. Thanks again.